# Octave/Matlab solution for analyzing data coming from network

Tags: sockets, matlab, network-programming, octave

I am currently doing some research which involves analyzing data coming from different sensors. The way the data is provided is via a network interface. I want to take advantage of the already written procedures available in matlab/octave (error computing, plotting etc).

Which one is the best approach for doing such things:

- doing an application in another language and call octave/matlab functions with data received from network?
- doing an application in octave/matlab which handles incoming data from network interface?

...

Any other solutions and experiences are highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Iulian

**LATER EDIT:**

I am more interested in using octave than matlab but currently I'm looking to see a working method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used it, but there's a [sockets package for Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/sockets/). If this works, writing the whole application in Octave seems easier to me than dealing with cross-language calling.

Answer (score 0):

The "doing an application in octave/matlab which handles incoming data from network interface?" should be (fairly) easy, as you can easily use Java objects in MATLAB. You can use the Java network interfaces (or possibly a wrapper around them, if that makes it easier for you). I've worked on projects that take this approach to have Java threads handle all the networking and allowing MATLAB to grab results from the Java periodically and display/process them.